# QGIS not responding when committing changes to a layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I run QGIS version 3.10.6 on my laptop, which runs Windows 10. The program is a bit slow on startup, but the real issue comes when I calculate a field on a layer to add to my attribute table. When I exit the edit mode and save these changes, the program stops responding.

I have already tried to disable plugins, which hasn't changed the situation. This is a fresh install on Windows.

Comment: I fear it's a problem with an extremely broad field of possible causes. Other software runs fine? Enough free memory? What kind of layer is it you try to update and how many features does it contain? What is the expression you use in field calculator? How many layers have you loaded and how are they displayed? Do you use some computationally intensive  symbolizations as heatmap rendering for (large) point layers? Have you also tried QGIS 3.16?

Comment: That's what I feared. Everything else does run fine on my computer, and memory isn't an issue as far as I can tell (it maxes out at 50% consumption alongside any other program running in background). I reinstalled QGIS and managed to save this time with only the affected layer, but when I tried the exact same thing on a new file it froze.

Comment: Elaborate in "the exact same thing": what exactly are you doing? Maybe a screenshot could help.

Comment: If your doing a fresh install of QGIS you also might manually need to delete the user folders of C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\QGIS